# Skip step in jobs that not contains tests

Tags: git, testing, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have split all my cypress tests in various jobs in my Gitab CI depending on domain (user, menu, timeline ...) like this I can execute in parallel all this jobs.

The problem is that I steel have this in for example the `cypress:user` job : [image]

So the job take more time than expected . For example a job without any tests executed takes 15min...

This is the command to launch a job :

```
docker run -v $PWD:/e2e -w /e2e --link=_nginx:myurl.test --net=_default cypress/included:3.4.0 node ./node_modules/.bin/cypress-tags run -e TAGS="${FEATURE_TAGS}" --config baseUrl=https://myurl.test --reporter junit --reporter-options "mochaFile=cypress/reports/[hash].xml"
```

Maybe someone know how to disable those useless steps in the job.
Thank you.

**EDIT**

The solution was to use this command instead :

```
docker run -v $PWD:/e2e -w /e2e --link=_nginx:myurl.test --net=_default cypress/included:4.5.0 node ./node_modules/.bin/cypress run -env --spec ${SPEC} --config baseUrl=https://myurl.test --reporter junit --reporter-options "mochaFile=cypress/reports/[hash].xml"
```

So the main solution was to use `--spec` instead of `tags`

Comment: Are your tests stored in files into a specific directory ?

Comment: Yes, I store a screenshot and a video for each test

Comment: I just remove the paths to the videos in my artifacts and it's the same. I will attempt to store the reports and screenshots only on failure.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger job only if there are [changes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlychangesexceptchanges) into a specific directory.

Example, if you have 2 jobs, one for user tests and the other one for menu tests, you can have something like this :

```
cypress_user:
  stage : test
  script: echo "executing my user tests"
  only:
    changes:
      - dir_where_user_tests_are_stored/

cypress_menu:
  stage : test
  script: echo "executing my menu tests"
  only:
    changes:
      - dir_where_menu_tests_are_stored/
```

`cypress_user`job will be executed only if files change in `dir_where_user_tests_are_stored` and `cypress_menu`job will be executed only if files change in `dir_where_menu_tests_are_stored`

Comment: I prefer launch every jobs to avoid side effects of a change . But thanks for your idea